# How to make effect of animate open collectionView in swift (like the video)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, uicollectionview

I try to make animation of open uicollectionview (like the video in the link), Someone have idea how to code it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3d1z.jpg

This link is example of how I won't the effect look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I succeed by anime with UIView.animate the UICollectionViewCell.layer.position attribute.